# ¿Como puedo personalizar un marcado de mapas en donde la parte de enmedio este con un circulo transparente?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estoy iniciando en la programación de Android studio. Y he estado checando la pagina de Android Developer en la plataforma de mapas. En la parte de personalizar un Marcador de mapas solo menciona cómo colocar una imagen en lugar del Pin rojo de ubicación por default en la API de Google Maps.

Revise estas paginas:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811579/how-to-create-a-custom-shaped-bitmap-marker-with-android-map-api-v2

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo colocar en medio del Marcador un circulo transparente, adjunto imagen?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Traduce el título de tu pregunta por favor

Comment: En tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Como puedo personalizar un marcador de mapas que en la parte de enmedio sea un circulo transparente en android studio?

Comment: quieres ponerle sombra o q? El marker tiene una opcion de poner icono creo, ahi le pasas tu imagen, una imagen de un pin con un circulo transparente.

Comment: Si ya me comentaron que necesito crear un grafico en formato vectorial de tipo svg, para que al hacer zoom sobre el mapa no se distorsione. Gracias